# Inline assembly errors: junk `-4(%ebp)' after register

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, kernel, inline-assembly

GCC tells  junk `-4(%ebp)' after register errors for my following codes:

```
  static __inline__ int xchg_asm(int* lock, int val)
    {
        int ret;

        __asm__ __volatile__(
                    LOCK "movl %1,%%eax;  xchg (%1),%2  ; movl %%eax %0"
                    :"=m" (ret)
                    :"d"(lock), "c"(val));
        return ret;
    }
```

I can't see how to modify it.

Comment: You're missing a `,` in the second `movl`.

Comment: Not related, but very important - define EAX in the list of clobbered data. Otherwise, GCC assumes EAX is unchanged by this code, and you may get nasty bugs.

Answer (score 0):

`gas` (the GNU assembler used by gcc) expects newlines as line endings, not semicolons. Did you try using `"\n"` instead of `";"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add '\n' after every asm insruction:

```
 __asm__ __volatile__(
                LOCK "movl %1,%%eax \n  xchg (%1),%2 \n movl %%eax, %0 \n"
                :"=m" (ret)
                :"d"(lock), "c"(val));
    return ret;
}
```

In case of such errors, compile the source to assembler file - using `-S` option of GCC and check the line that was reported by gas.

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing

> LOCK "movl %1,%%eax;  xchg (%1),%2  ; movl %%eax %0"

is missing a semicolon befor it's last argument.